# Smart-Shaming: A Threat to the Age of Information

Tags: punctuation, word-usage

I would like to inquire if the above mentioned title is correct. I will be using it as a title for my article on our school's newspaper.

Comment: If you mean that students who are smart get a message from other students that they are not cool,  then that is a threat not only to the age of information, but to innovation in all fields.   This is not new; smart was not cool when I was in High School, eons ago.  Fortunately, those of us who were smart were smart enough to know not to be obnoxious about it, and to know that we would eventually wind up as winners.  As for the grammar, it is fine.

Comment: Nothing wrong, other than you violated the rule on proofreading.

Comment: Nobody can tell you if your title is *semantically* correct or not. If you're asking if it's grammatically correct, proofreading is off topic unless you have a specific concern.

Comment: Titles don't generally need to be grammatically correct. They need to be terse, and this often involves removing words that can be inferred. For instance, your title no verb, that OK.